# Non-constant analytic function on an open connected subset $U$ of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, analytic-functions

Let $U\subset \mathbb{C} $ be an open connected set and  $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a non-constant analytic function. Consider the following sets:-

$X=\{z\in U:f(z)=0\}$

$Y=\{z\in U:f $ vanishes on an open neighbourhood of z in $ U\} $

Then which of the following statements are true?

$(a)\;X$ is closed in $U$

$(b)\;Y$ is closed in $U$

$(c)\;X$ has empty interior

$(d)\;Y$ is open in $U$

My thoughts:-

For $(a)$:

$X=f^-\{0\}$ and $\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{C}$ and inverse image of closed set under a continuous function is closed. So $X$ is closed in $U$.

For $(c)$:

Since zeroes of an analytic function are isolated, so it is true.

Now, for $(b)$ and $(d)$:

If $Y=\emptyset$, then it is both open and closed in $U$.

Else if $Y\neq \emptyset$, then $Y=U$ by uniqueness theorem which again is both closed and open in $U$. So $(b)$ and $(d)$ are true.

Please give a review on my answer and suggest possible corrections/refinements to it.

Comment: Your answers are all correct.

Comment: Additional comment: I think you can even rule out the possibility that $Y = U$ since $f$ is assumed to be non-constant.